# How to add people to Circle in Google+ using Google+ API?

Tags: c#, web-applications, google-plus

I've browsed through all content in https://developers.google.com and can't find a way to do that. Does anyone have idea or did this before, please help me out this. Any helpful info would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation page to do this : 
[Add a person to a circle](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/circles/addPeople)

Comment: That API is limited exclusively for use by Google Apps accounts and will not work with Gmail accounts.